# ProgressBar not showing

Tags: android, webview, android-progressbar

I am currently trying to make a wheel progress bar show while the web view is currently loading. Having some troubles with my code. Any idea on what is wrong or missing with my code?

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

This is my code on the web view part.

```
setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
    wv1 = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.wv1);
    wv1.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);
    wv1.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
    wv1.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
    wv1.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    wv1.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    wv1.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    wv1.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);


    final Activity activity = this;

    wv1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView viewx, String urlx) {
            viewx.loadUrl(urlx);
            return false;
        }

        public void onProgressChanged (WebView view, int progress){
            activity.setTitle("Loading..");
            activity.setProgress(progress * 100);

            if (progress == 100) 
                setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
            activity.setTitle("My Title");
        }
    }

            );



    wv1.loadUrl(nFeed);
```

Comment: you should use ProgressDialog and dismiss() it in onPageFinished() of WebViewClient.

Answer (score 0):

You should load the webview in an Async Task and add the progress bar in the onpreexecute method then dismiss it in the onPostexecute method

Answer (score 0):

Cam Connor's answer is incorrect. Your code looks okay on first glance.

You know that this loading wheel is supposed to show on the action bar? Do you have a (large) action bar in your app?